# "much exciting" vs. "very exciting"

Tags: adverb-placement

> The hockey match between india and pakistan was **much** exciting.

Here, i think there should be  **very** at the place of  *much*. If both are correct then what the difference in the meaning. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You're right, "very" should be used in place of "much". "Much exciting" is incorrect.

### Why?

"Much", **when functioning as an adverb that modifies an adjective**, is used to modify comparative adjectives. "Exciting" by itself, is not a comparative adjective, but the examples below are:

- (much) more exciting
- (much) more interesting
- (much) less exciting
- (much) less interesting
- (much) colder
- (much) warmer